# Arduino Sketch Crashes in working procedure when adding extra call

Tags: arduino-mega, sketch

I am trying to drive a couple of motors to make a car.
I successfully wrote some code then tidied it up to procedurise it and it just kept crashing.
I've put some debug code in and narrowed it down a bit but what I am seeing makes no sense. With the code below I just call the TLeft procedure which works and drives the motor and I get the serial output:
RWheel Forward
1
2
3
4
5
ReTurn L
RWheel Forward
1
2
3
4
5
ReTurn L
RWheel Forward
1
2
3
4
5
ReTurn L

```
/************************
  Exercise the motor using
  the L293D chip
************************/

#define RW_ENABLE 11
#define RW_DIRA 28
#define RW_DIRB 30
#define LW_ENABLE 10
#define LW_DIRA 48
#define LW_DIRB 50

int i;

void setup() {
  //---set pin direction
  pinMode(RW_ENABLE, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RW_DIRA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RW_DIRB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LW_ENABLE, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LW_DIRA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LW_DIRB, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Prog Start");
  delay(1000);
}



void loop(){
    //Serial.println("Wheels Forwards");
  //GoForward();
  //delay(2000);
  //Serial.println("Turn Left");
  TLeft();
  Serial.println("ReTurn L");
  delay(5000);
  //Serial.println("Turn Right");
  //TRight();
  delay(5000);
  //Serial.println("Wheels Backwards");
  //Backwards();
  delay(5000);
  //Stop();
  delay(5000);
}



void TRight() {
  Serial.println("LWheel Forwards");
  delay(1000);
  analogWrite(LW_ENABLE, 254); //halfspeed
  digitalWrite(LW_DIRA, HIGH); //one way
  digitalWrite(LW_DIRB, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RW_ENABLE, LOW); //RWheel off

}
void TLeft() {
  Serial.println("RWheel Forward");
  delay(1000);
  analogWrite(RW_ENABLE, 254); //halfspeed
  Serial.println("1");
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(RW_DIRA, HIGH); //one way
  Serial.println("2");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("3");
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(RW_DIRB, LOW);
  Serial.println("4");
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(LW_ENABLE, LOW); //RWheel off
  Serial.println("5");
  delay(1000);

}
void Backwards() {
    Serial.println("Both Back");
    analogWrite(LW_ENABLE, 250); //halfspeed
    digitalWrite(LW_DIRA, LOW); //back
    digitalWrite(LW_DIRB, HIGH);
    analogWrite(RW_ENABLE, 250); //halfspeed
    digitalWrite(RW_DIRA, LOW); //back
    digitalWrite(RW_DIRB, HIGH);
  }

void Forwards() {
  Serial.println("Both Forw");
  analogWrite(LW_ENABLE, 250); //halfspeed
  digitalWrite(LW_DIRA, HIGH); //one way
  digitalWrite(LW_DIRB, LOW);
  analogWrite(RW_ENABLE, 250); //halfspeed
  digitalWrite(RW_DIRA, HIGH); //one way
  digitalWrite(RW_DIRB, LOW);
}


void Stop () {
  Serial.println("Stop");
  digitalWrite(LW_ENABLE, LOW); //halfspeed
  digitalWrite(LW_DIRA, HIGH); //one way
  digitalWrite(LW_DIRB, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RW_ENABLE, LOW); //halfspeed
  digitalWrite(RW_DIRA, HIGH); //one way
  digitalWrite(RW_DIRB, LOW);

}
```

---

When I uncomment out the call to Backwards as below.....

```
/************************
  Exercise the motor using
  the L293D chip
************************/

#define RW_ENABLE 11
#define RW_DIRA 28
#define RW_DIRB 30
#define LW_ENABLE 10
#define LW_DIRA 48
#define LW_DIRB 50

int i;

void setup() {
  //---set pin direction
  pinMode(RW_ENABLE, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RW_DIRA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RW_DIRB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LW_ENABLE, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LW_DIRA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LW_DIRB, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Prog Start");
  delay(1000);
}



void loop(){
    //Serial.println("Wheels Forwards");
  //GoForward();
  //delay(2000);
  //Serial.println("Turn Left");
  TLeft();
  Serial.println("ReTurn L");
  delay(5000);
  //Serial.println("Turn Right");
  //TRight();
  delay(5000);
  //Serial.println("Wheels Backwards");
  Backwards();
  delay(5000);
  //Stop();
  delay(5000);
}



void TRight() {
  Serial.println("LWheel Forwards");
  delay(1000);
  analogWrite(LW_ENABLE, 254); //halfspeed
  digitalWrite(LW_DIRA, HIGH); //one way
  digitalWrite(LW_DIRB, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RW_ENABLE, LOW); //RWheel off

}
void TLeft() {
  Serial.println("RWheel Forward");
  delay(1000);
  analogWrite(RW_ENABLE, 254); //halfspeed
  Serial.println("1");
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(RW_DIRA, HIGH); //one way
  Serial.println("2");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("3");
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(RW_DIRB, LOW);
  Serial.println("4");
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(LW_ENABLE, LOW); //RWheel off
  Serial.println("5");
  delay(1000);

}
void Backwards() {
    Serial.println("Both Back");
    analogWrite(LW_ENABLE, 250); //halfspeed
    digitalWrite(LW_DIRA, LOW); //back
    digitalWrite(LW_DIRB, HIGH);
    analogWrite(RW_ENABLE, 250); //halfspeed
    digitalWrite(RW_DIRA, LOW); //back
    digitalWrite(RW_DIRB, HIGH);
  }

void Forwards() {
  Serial.println("Both Forw");
  analogWrite(LW_ENABLE, 250); //halfspeed
  digitalWrite(LW_DIRA, HIGH); //one way
  digitalWrite(LW_DIRB, LOW);
  analogWrite(RW_ENABLE, 250); //halfspeed
  digitalWrite(RW_DIRA, HIGH); //one way
  digitalWrite(RW_DIRB, LOW);
}


void Stop () {
  Serial.println("Stop");
  digitalWrite(LW_ENABLE, LOW); //halfspeed
  digitalWrite(LW_DIRA, HIGH); //one way
  digitalWrite(LW_DIRB, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RW_ENABLE, LOW); //halfspeed
  digitalWrite(RW_DIRA, HIGH); //one way
  digitalWrite(RW_DIRB, LOW);

}
```

It seems to crash in the TLeft procedure, no motor turns and I get the serial output:
Prog Start
RWheel Forward
Prog Start
RWheel Forward
Prog Start
RWheel Forward
Prog Start
RWheel Forward
Prog Start

I even bought a new Arduino mega thinking it was a hardware fault, downloaded the program to the new mega which has no hardware connections at all just connected to the serial port to download the program and it crashes in exactly the same way.
How can adding another call make it fail in the bit of code that previously ran ok? This is driving me nuts. Can anyone help please?
Also I noticed in the Arduino program installation area there is a program called Arduino_debug.exe, what is this and how does one use it?

Comment: which version of Arduino AVR boards you use? I would try the old 1.6.21. The newer versions have have updated compiler and there are problems reported.

Comment: Looks so strange that I guess it's a power supply problem when your motor wants to run. Are you sure it happens on a naked Arduino the same way? i.E. you don't see the "1" output after your `analogWrite(11,254);` ?

Comment: Yes it happens on the new naked board. I don't see the "1" output. It just reboots.

Comment: did you try to install AVR boards package 1.6.21 in Boards Manager?

Comment: Your code (including the Backwards part) runs without issues on my Mega2560 and Arduino 1.8.9.

Comment: I had version 1.8.1, I tried downloading 1.6.21 but wouldn't download , so tried 1.8.2, no difference. I then tried 1.6.20 and that made no difference. I then uninstalled arduino and re-installed it, and phew it now works ok.

Comment: Thanks for help in assuring me it must have been some environment related issue. I'm thinking it might have been something to do with trying out different learning projects which required installation of different libraries. I installed the pitches library and a remote library. There is plenty of info telling you how to add a new library and sometimes it says one library may interfere with another. But I cannot find any information on how to remove a library to avoid interference. A complete uninstall and re-install is a bit overthe top.